# Unable to connect to Cloud MySQL from Node JS in App Engine

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a NodeJS app with MySQL that works locally, but now I have deployed it in APP Engine and I need to connect it with MySQL Google Cloud, I have created the MySQL instance and the database but I can't connect my app (NodeJS in App Engine) with my database in MySQL cloud, I am using the following code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "host-IP",
  socketPath: "/cloudsql/project:region:instance",
  user: "USERNAME",
  password: "USERPASSWORD"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

module.exports = con;
```

Archivo .YAML---------------------------

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
env_variables:
  SQL_USER: "USERNAME"
  SQL_PASSWORD: "USERPASSWORD"
  SQL_DATABASE: "DBNAME"
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: "project:region:instance"
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "project:region:instance"
```

Please help me.

Comment: leaving mysql open to attacks from the internet is a very very bad idea. read up on REST where you have a serverside script which handles all traffuc

Comment: @nbk Sorry i am new, please can you explain me little bit more about you say and how i can solve the problem to leaving mysql open to attacks, please!

Comment: node js is already a serverside script and you want to access mysql data, that is in the cloud. As you should make the mysql server available, you have some possibilities, you write a nodes js script for the cloud with will run on the clud server or you write a php script with the same intent or you write a angularjs script that you can cakk with ajax which gets you the data from the cloud server. When i think about it, why don't run your nodejs nt directly in the cloud?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to connect to a Cloud SQL instance from App Engine Flexible. You can either connect through the Public or the Private IP of the instance.

My suggestion would be to connect through Private IP because connections over private IP provide lower latency and limited attack vectors, as they don't require traversing the internet.

Assuming that you already have an instance and connecting through Public IP here are the steps:

1. Create a [database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-databases#create) and [a user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users) in your Cloud SQL instance.
2. Get the `instance_connection_name` for your instance. It can be found by the instance Overview, the `gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]` command. It has a `projectID:region:instanceName` format.
3. Grant the service account your app uses to authenticate calls to Cloud SQL one of the following Cloud SQL roles that include the `cloudsql.instances.connect` and
   `cloudsql.instances.get` permissions:

   - Cloud SQL Client
   - Cloud SQL Editor
   - Cloud SQL Admin

   *Two things to keep in mind here is that App Engine, by default uses the App Engine flexible environment service account, which has Editor role granted and that if the service account which is used belongs to a different project than the Cloud SQL instance, the Cloud SQL Admin API and IAM permissions will need to be added for both projects.*
4. Configure your `app.yaml` according to the option you wish to connect through:

   **Unix sockets**

   ```
   beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
   ```

   **TCP port**

   ```
   beta_settings:
     cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME:port
   ```
5. Include the following env variables:

   ```
    env_variables:
      DB_USER: MY_DB_USER
      DB_PASS: MY_DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: MY_DATABASE
      # e.g. my-awesome-project:us-central1:my-cloud-sql-instance
      CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: <MY-PROJECT>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>
   ```

*Keep in mind that `DB_NAME` is the name of the database you created earlier where `INSTANCE-NAME` is the name of your Cloud SQL instance.*

6. Finally, use the following snippet to configure the connection:

   ```
    const createUnixSocketPool = async (config) => {
      const dbSocketPath = process.env.DB_SOCKET_PATH || "/cloudsql"

      // Establish a connection to the database
      return await mysql.createPool({
        user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-db-user'
        password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-db-password'
        database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
        // If connecting via unix domain socket, specify the path
        socketPath: `${dbSocketPath}/${process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
        // Specify additional properties here.
        ...config
      });
    }
   ```

You may find all the details in [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible#connecting_to) and [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql)